# Issue with java DateFormat

Tags: java, parsing, date, date-format, simpledateformat

Following is a piece of code that I am running.

```
@Test
public void testMyMehotd() {
    String expected = "2012-09-12T20:13:47.796327Z";
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z'");
    //df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    Date d = null;
    try {
        d = df.parse(expected);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    String actual = df.format(d);

    System.out.println(expected);
    System.out.println(actual);

}
```

but the output is different than what I expect.

```
expected : 2012-09-12T20:13:47.796327Z
actual   : 2012-09-12T20:27:03.000327Z
```

Can someone tell me the reason for this and what is the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you are printing date instead of d

Comment: Is defining SSSSSS in the date format means that is micro seconds??/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you exceed `999` milliseconds, `DateFormat` will try to ***add*** the remaining milliseconds to your date. Consider the following simpler example:

```
 String expected = "2012-09-12T20:13:47.1001Z";
 DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSS'Z'");
 Date d = df.parse(expected);
```

The resulting date will be `2012-09-12T20:13:48.0001`. That is, since you have `1001` milliseconds, you get `1` *extra* second (`1000` milliseconds), and `1` millisecond (`1001 % 1000`). Thus instead of `47` seconds as in the original date, you get `48` seconds.

---

This is also what happens if you try to parse a date with an invalid number of days in a month. For example, if you try to add an extra day to September, and parse `2012-09-31`:

```
String expected = "2012-09-31";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date d = df.parse(expected);
System.out.println(df.format(d));
```

You'll actually get `2012-10-01`. Again, that's because `DateFormat` will detect that the 31st day of September is not *valid*, and will try to use heuristics to *transform* the `Date`, thus adding one day, ending up with the first day of the next month.

There's an option to tell the parser not to use these heuristics, by setting **[lenient](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient%28boolean%29)** mode to `false` with:

```
df.setLenient(false);
```

However, using this mode, both above examples will throw a `ParseException`.

Comment: Thnx for the answer. Is SSSSSS in the format means those are microsecs??

Comment: @Sashwat: No, it doesn't really matter how many `S` you use, a single one will suffice to match milliseconds. But when in lenient mode, `S` will match as many milliseconds as you have, and attempt to use heuristics to do something with it (adding time to the original date).

Answer (score 2):

`S` means millisecond and you passed 796327 milliseconds. That number is equal to 13[min]:16[sec]:327[millis] so additional minutes and seconds ware added to your date.